# How to gather changes made in RTF document?

Tags: c#, rtf, change-tracking

I am trying to gather all tracked changes from RTF file (track changes already enabled).
I have checked documentation but I have not found much helpful data.

Comment: You mean using MS Office SDK to get tracked changes ?

Comment: Well, any method to get this will be helpful. I tried to find anything useful in Interops with no success